# How to make 1 table scrollable with fixed header without affecting other tables in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, django, twitter-bootstrap

I have spent over a day figuring out something very simple. I have a website where I use about 10 tables. I want only 1 of those 10 tables to have a fixed header and a scrollable bar.

I found a good example online and modified it. I am able to have a table with fixed header and scrollable bar.

**New css**

```
.table-fixed tbody {
    display:block;
    max-height:625px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
.table-fixed thead, tbody tr {
    display:table;
    width:100%;
    table-layout:fixed;
}
.table-fixed thead {
    width: calc( 100% - 1em )
}
```

I add the *table-fixed* class to my table definition and it works.

```
<table class = "table table-bordered table-hover table-striped table-condensed table-fixed">
```

The problem is that if I do not include the table-fixed in the other tables, the 9 other tables are all screwed up. For example:

**No table-fixed class added to the other tables**

```
      <table class = "table table-bordered table-hover table-striped table-condensed">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">something</th>
            <th style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">something</th>
            <th style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">something</th>
            <th style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">something</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">something</td>
              <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">something</td>
              <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">something</td>
              <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">something</td>
            </tr>
        <tbody>
      </table>
```

[image: Top header is good, body is all in one cell]

How can I fix this issue? I want the changes to CSS to only affect 1 table. My table-fixed class works, but it looks like I am modifying the tbody where it affects it globally. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Add the css you want into a different css class and only add it to the one table you want changed.

Comment: I am new to css, and I am confuse on your comment. I did create a new class called table-fixed where I defined  the attributes. Then I add this css class to the table I want only. Is that not creating a new class?

Comment: Yea it is, but you were saying it also affected the other tables? If you just add that class to the one table that should solve your issue or take the `table-fixed` class out of all your other tables.

Comment: That is exactly what I am doing. I add the `table-fixed` to 1 table only. The other tables have the `table` class as shown above. But somehow the modifications of `.table-fixed` changes the `table` class as well.

Comment: try this:

.table-fixed > tbody {
    display:block;
    max-height:625px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
.table-fixed > thead, tbody tr {
    display:table;
    width:100%;
    table-layout:fixed;
}
.table-fixed > thead {
    width: calc( 100% - 1em )
}

Comment: The only difference I see is the greater than symbol `>`. I added that and my tables are in the unwanted format as shown on my question. Keep in mind that I completely remove the `table-fixed` from any table definition and this is happening. If I were to remove the css modification, it would go back to normal.

Comment: Yea it just makes sure it only affect immediate children. you could also try this, don't add the table-fixed class to any of your tables and they should remain unaffected. .table-fixed > tbody {
    display:block;
    max-height:625px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

.table-fixed > thead > tr {
    display:table;
    width:100%;
    table-layout:fixed;
}

.table-fixed > tbody > tr {
    display:table;
    width:100%;
    table-layout:fixed;
}

.table-fixed > thead {
    width: calc( 100% - 1em );
}

Comment: If that doesn't work, then if you could stick it in a bootply or a fiddle then I'll take a look at it.

Comment: It worked with a slight adjustment. After running your suggested modifications the tables were not affected. I then added the fixed-table class and it worked well with a minor defect. The header and body did not match in column width. Therefore I removed the `> tr` from your suggested code `.table-fixed > thead > tr>{...` and it worked perfectly. I appreciate your help a lot!

Comment: Good to hear, you're welcome. Happy to help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit to  sringland.

I modified the original code:

```
.table-fixed tbody {
    display:block;
    max-height:625px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
.table-fixed thead, tbody tr {
    display:table;
    width:100%;
    table-layout:fixed;
}
.table-fixed thead {
    width: calc( 100% - 1em )
}
```

To this:

```
.table-fixed > tbody {
    display:block;
    max-height:625px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
.table-fixed > thead {
    display:table;
    width:100%;
    table-layout:fixed;
}
.table-fixed > tbody > tr {
  display:table;
  width:100%;
  table-layout:fixed;
}
.table-fixed > thead {
    width: calc( 100% - 1em )
}
```

The issue was resolved by adding the `>` to only affect immediate children and to break up the `thead, tbody tr {` definition because it was affecting the tbody of the `Table` class.